# How To Store RSA private,public keys

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, private-key

I am developing an android messaging app. When user signup rsa private and public key are generated and with these keys and aes messages are encrypted and decrypted.

Private key is stored in the phone and public key in the server. If the user resets or uninstall the app all keys are lost so there is no way to decrypt the old messages.

How can I retrieve old private keys without storing it in server when user uninstalls app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Android Keystore to store the keys or using your own file storage?

**Android keystore**

With Android Keystore there is no way to recover keys because they can only be used by the application that created them and are discarded if there are substantial changes.

I guess you are using the RSA keys to negotiate an AES symmetric encryption key. Therefore you will need to backup the AES encryption key( for example in the server...),  and stablish a mechanism to recover the key like the common "remember password" utilities

**custom key storage**

If you are storing the keys into the device without AndroidKeystore, you could define your own mechanism to restore the keys. For example, encrypt the key with a password and storing the key into a public directory of the device. Then the key can be recovered prompting user for the password

**Note**: Take into account the security risks in each case. For example a non-encrypted AES keys into server implies that a malicious server could decrypt messages. Or a weak recovery key mechanism will descrease the whole security level of the system

Comment: message is encrypted with randomly generated aes key which r unique for each message  sent and the aes key is encrypted using rsa and sent with the message.after the message is delivered its deleted from the server.the problem occurs when a message is waiting to be deliverd in the server and the user resets the app it also resets the public n private key upon which it was encrypted

Comment: Then you need a backup for the RSA private key not attached to the application to be available if the application is restarted. Encrypt the RSA key with a password as I commented above. And store the key into server or in a persistent file on the device itself. The drawback is that you need to request a password to the user and this is not user-friendly

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to persist data in Android. Databases, SavedInstanceState, SharePreferences and files. Only files persist after you application is unInstalled by the user. Saving it in a file is about the only option you have.

Comment: right now its been stored in DB and sharedprefernce.does keystore persist data after app is uninstalled.